# Oyster card—London only?

Tags: public-transport, where-on-earth, tfl, oyster-card

I vaguely remember using an "Oyster card" somewhere other than London.  But perhaps I am misremembering.  Is there another place that uses that term for transit?

Answer (score 2):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=oyster%20card%20-london&gws_rd=cr&fg=1) for "Oyster Card" excluding "London" suggests there is no such place.

What you remember is possibly Hong Kong's [Octopus card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus_card), whose success later inspired the Oyster card.

Comment: Or the Dutch OV kaart, (OV pass) which is a later version and for all public transport in the country.

Comment: Damn. What about vegetarian cards, then?

Comment: Well, it wasn't the first time I was in London.  So it was probably London.  Last time I was in Hong Kong was in the 1970s.  I don't think they were using RFID then.